# Trennbare Verben und Wortstellung

Tags: grammar, separable-verb

> **This question also has an answer here (in English):**
>
> - [Putting (part of) separable verb at beginning of sentence?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/23985)

Ich glaube, dass die Antwort "auf keinen Fall" ist, aber ich wollte fragen, ob es möglich wäre, das trennbare Präfix eines Verbes an den Anfang eines Satzes zu schieben wegen der Wortstellungsfreiheit.

Ich habe Sätze wie "Gestorben ist er..." häufig gesehen, was der Idee, dass das zweite Verb am Ende kommen muss, widerspricht. Deshalb frage ich mich, ob etwas wie Folgendes möglich wäre

> *Vor ziehe ich das Buch dem Film* anstatt *Ich ziehe das Buch dem Film vor*

Ich kann mir nicht vorstellen warum ich das sagen wollen würde, aber ich bin neugierig, ob es absolut und fraglos falsch ist oder nicht.

Answer (score 8):

Es ist möglich, aber sehr ungewöhnlich; sehr viel ungewöhnlicher als ein Satz wie *Gestorben ist er an einem Herzinfarkt*, in dem das *gestorben* stark betont ist, häufig, um einen Kontrast herzustellen:

> Gestorben ist er an einem Herzinfarkt, aber er hatte auch einen bösartigen Hirntumor.

Am ehesten würde man ein abgetrenntes Präfix am Satzanfang verwenden, wenn man zwei verschiedene Präfixe mit demselben Grundverb gegeneinanderstellt:

> *Auf* sind sie *gestiegen*, nicht *ab*.
>   *Auf* *steigen* sie, nicht *ab*.

Das wird in gesprochener Sprache durchaus verwendet, als stilistisch gut gilt es aber nicht. Dichter haben natürlich ihre Freiheiten:

> *Auf* *steigt* der Strahl und fallend gießt
>   er voll der Marmorschale Rund ...

(Conrad Ferdinand Meyer, [Der römische Brunnen](https://de.wikisource.org/wiki/Der_r%C3%B6mische_Brunnen))

In Zeiten mit Hilfsverb ist es viel besser, beide Teile gemeinsam nach vorne zu ziehen:

> *Aufgestiegen* sind sie, nicht *abgestiegen*.

In anderen Zeiten ist das nur möglich, wenn man die zweite Position im Satz anderweitig besetzt, und zwar mit dem Verb *tun*:

> *Aufsteigen* tun sie, nicht *absteigen*.

Das kommt umgangssprachlich oder regional so vor, ist aber stilistisch richtig unschön. Ich rate davon ab, es zu benutzen, vor allem in geschriebenen Texten.

Comment: "Vor ziehe ich" halte ich keineswegs für möglich. Das ist Yoda speak, aber kein Deutsch.

Comment: Es ist grenzwertig, klar; für manche schon jenseits der Grenze, für andere gerade noch akzeptabel. *Sehr ungewöhnlich* in jedem Fall, wie ich oben sagte.

Answer (score 4):

Ist es möglich? Ja. Du hast den Satz gebildet und wir haben ihn verstanden. Selbst ohne die direkte Gegenüberstellung mit der Normalform hätten wir ihn verstehen können.

Wird das oft so gemacht? Nein, extrem selten. Ich zum Beispiel habe die Konstruktion öfter in Fragen auf Stackexchange gesehen als im Leben.

Heißt das, daß sie "falsch" ist? Das hängt von der Sprachauffassung ab. "Präskriptiv" aufgefaßt, sind extrem seltene Varianten einfach nur falsch. "Deskriptiv" aufgefaßt, sind sie dispräferiert, weil das Verständnis weniger gesichert ist, aber nützlich, wenn jemand sie doch bildet und verstanden wird. Es gibt keinen geheimen, tiefer liegenden Unterschied, der entscheiden könnte, ob eine Konstruktion "wirklich" richtig oder falsch sei - Grammatik ist eben *nicht* logisch aus einigen Grundprinzipien ableitbar.